# How to convert PyObject to UTF-8 string?

Tags: c++, utf-8, python-3.6, unicode-string, python-extensions

I'm trying to pass a string value to a Python function and get a utf-8 string value. The function retrieves Japanese characters and returns characters in another language.

I used `ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW` in the Python script and made sure there is no problem with the Python function. And I tried a simple function like `return 'hello world'` to test. I also checked every function with `assert`. I guess the problem starts with `PyBytes_AsString`. It always returns `DB DB DB DB DB DB DB...` (in hex). But I don't know how to fix this.

```
char* result;
PyObject* module, *func, *arg, *ret, *value;

Py_Initialize();

PyObject* sysPath = PySys_GetObject("path");
PyObject* path = PyUnicode_FromString(".");
PyList_Append(sysPath, path);

module = PyImport_ImportModule("test");

if (module != 0)
{
    const wchar_t* w = L"翻訳テスト";
    func = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "translate");
    arg = PyTuple_New(1);
    value = PyUnicode_FromWideChar(w, wcslen(w));
    PyTuple_SetItem(arg, 0, value);
    ret = PyObject_CallObject(func, arg);

    PyObject* repr = PyObject_Repr(ret);
    PyObject* str = PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(repr, "utf-8", "strict");
    result = PyBytes_AsString(str);

    Py_DECREF(repr);
    Py_DECREF(str);
    Py_DECREF(module);
    Py_DECREF(func);
    Py_DECREF(arg);
    Py_DECREF(ret);

    fstream file("text.txt", std::ios::out);
    file << result;
    file.close();
}

Py_Finalize();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result = PyBytes_AsString(str)` returns a pointer to the internal buffer of `str`, so don't `Py_DECREF(str)` before you write `result` to the file.

Comment: Thank you. I feel retarded. I wasted a day for this..... I really appreciate you.